# my app using google maps service and not load map on Huawei device(tablet HarmoneyOS)

Tags: flutter

[image]
my google map not load on Huawei tablet (HarmoneyOS 4.x.x)
say your app won't run with out google play services which are not supported by your device

i'm using flutter packages
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_widget

Comment: Google company has banned Huawei from google  tools

Answer (score 0):

Huawei phone/tablet devices released after May 2019 do not have GMS (Google Moblie Services). For those phones/tablets, you will need to use:

. Google Map Web version

. Huawei has its own map solution similar to Google Map, you can integrate Huawei Map Kit Plugin for Flutter: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/flutter-plugin-integrating-plugin-0000001252461503

. Use 3rd party Map SDK like Mapbox ect..: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/